# the var rate of 1000 can't determine the string?

Tags: if-statement

When I input the BSIT in the prompt, the rate is always 1200 even though the string is correct

```
<html> <HEAD>
<TITLE> Simple Enrollment Computation </TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
<!--hide  

alert('Hi, Welcome!');
var yourname = prompt('Please enter your name.');
var course = prompt('Enter your Course');
var units= prompt('Enter number of units:');
if ( (course = 'BSIT') || (course = 'bsit') )
{
    var rate = 1000
}
else ( (course == ' ') || (course == null) )
{
    var rate = 1200
}

var total=  rate * units
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code that throws the path of execution off.

An `else` clause never takes a condition - if the condition on the `if` evaluates to *false*, the `else` is executed - and in your code snippet that means that the test behind the `else` is evaluated. However, since the result is never assigned to anything, it is lost. The block right behind that is executed no matter what, thereby unconditionally setting *rate* to a value of 1200.

**Original statement, with annotations and slightly reformatted:**

> ```
> if ( (course = 'BSIT') || (course = 'bsit') )
> {
> // Will be executed when course == 'BSIT' or 'bsit'
>     var rate = 1000
> }
> // If course == ' ' or null, else is invoked, and since the condition
> // is directly following the else, that is evaluated.
> else 
>     ( (course == ' ') || (course == null) )
> // The following block is NOT attached to the else and so gets executed
> // no matter what!
> {
>     var rate = 1200
> }
> ```

Your best bet would be to either put an `if` right behind the `else` (this way the condition has an effect, and the previously dangling block becomes part of the second `if` statement) or change it into a `switch` statement.

**Modified if statement:**

```
var rate;      // One declaration is entirely sufficient.

if((course == 'BSIT') || (course == 'bsit'))
  {
  rate = 1000;
  }
else
  if((course == ' ') || (course == null))
    {
    rate = 1200;
    }
```

**switch statement:**

```
var rate;

switch(course)
  {
  case 'BSIT':
  case 'bsit':
    rate = 1000;
    break;

  case ' ':
  case null:
    rate = 1200;
    break;
  }
```

Each variant is going to fix that problem, however, you are going to wind up with an undefined value in `rate` if anything else than the expected values is entered. You should also account for that and assign a default value before doing any checks.